# Django saving some fields to the DB but not others

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, formset

I'm trying to save some data through a form and I'm trying to use a
`FormSet`. The data to be saved is an invoice which contains a `Product`
and it's `Details`.

I was able to render everything in one place (this wasn't simple) and
to save the invoice and the detail to the DB. For some reason, the
`Detail` table is saving the Product ID but not the Invoice ID.  This is
my `models.py`:

```py
class Detail(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9 , null=True, decimal_places=2)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='0000000000')
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9 , null=True, decimal_places=2)
```

And this is my `views.py`:

```
def invoice_new(request):
    DetailFormSet = formset_factory(DetailForm, extra=2)
    if request.method == "POST":
        invoice_form = InvoiceForm(request.POST)
        detail_formset = DetailFormSet(request.POST)
        if invoice_form.is_valid() and detail_formset.is_valid():
            invoice = invoice_form.save(commit=False)
            invoice.save()
            for details in detail_formset:
                details.save()
            return redirect('invoice_detail', pk=invoice.pk)
        else:
            return redirect('invoice_error')
    else:
        invoice_form = InvoiceForm()
        detail_formset=formset_factory(DetailForm, extra=2)
        return render(request, 'invoice/invoice_edit.html', {'invoice_form': invoice_form, 'detail_form': detail_formset} )
```

I tried adding this to the body of the `for` loop:

```
details.invoice_id = invoice.pk
```

`invoice.id` prints OK, but it won't save the number to the DB. I don't see how it picks up product id just fine but not invoice's.

I'm adding `forms.py`

```
class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ['date','number','supplier']
        total = forms.DecimalField(disabled=True)

class DetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Detail
        fields = ['product','quantity']
```

Comment: Show your forms.py code

Comment: Added, @UsmanMaqbool :)

Comment: I think I found the problem, although I don't know how to solve it yet. ```detail_formset = DetailFormSet(request.POST)``` is taking only the data from the form, I need to add another parameter so it takes the invoice ID. Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the invoice id before saving the form.

```
    if invoice_form.is_valid() and detail_formset.is_valid():
        invoice = invoice_form.save(commit=False)
        invoice.save()
        for details in detail_formset:
            details.invoice = invoice # Set the invoice
            details.save()
```

Comment: I moved to a totally different approach because I couldn't make this work. I think I saved this old version, I'll see if I can give it a try. Thank you!